# Symfony, collection, multiple entity, got arrayCollection, need entity

Tags: symfony, formbuilder, symfony-2.8

On old project with symfony 2.8,

i have 3 type of value (computedValue, manualData, probeData)
I have a entity name 'dataSource' that contains the 3 source, but only one can be set ( the 2 other is set to null )

I have other entity that contains 3 DataSource, and 3 ArrayCollection of DataSource.

I make my form like this:

```
        ...
        ->add('dsRef1', DataSourceType::class, [
            'site' => $site,
            'multiple' => false,
            'label_format' => 'form.%name%Ref1',
        ])


        ->add('dsList1', DataSourceType::class, [
            'site' => $site,
            'multiple' => true,
            'label_format' => 'form.%name%List1',
        ])
        ... ( 3 time , dsRef1 - 3 , dlList1 - 3 )
```

My DataSourceType is:

```
        $builder
        // This value is added for force symfony to think the form is submit when the form need to be empty
        ->add('hiddenCrapValue', HiddenType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => [
                'front-attr' => [
                    'render' => 'hidden',
                ],
            ],
        ])
        ->add(DataSourceInterface::DATA_SOURCE, ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $site->getDataSources(),
            'choices_as_values' => true,
            'multiple' => $multiple,
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'label_format' => $labelFormat,
        ])
        ->add(DataSourceInterface::PROBE_DATA, EntityType::class, [
            'class' => ProbeData::class,
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => $multiple,
            'attr' => [
                'front-attr' => [
                    'render' => 'hidden',
                ],
            ],
        ])
        ->add(DataSourceInterface::MANUAL_DATA, EntityType::class, [
            'class' => ManualData::class,
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => $multiple,
            'attr' => [
                'front-attr' => [
                    'render' => 'hidden',
                ],
            ],
        ])
        ->add(DataSourceInterface::COMPUTED_VALUE, EntityType::class, [
            'class' => ComputedValue::class,
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => $multiple,
            'attr' => [
                'front-attr' => [
                    'render' => 'hidden',
                ],
            ],
        ])
    ;
```

That work for my ref ( dsRef1, dsRef2, dsRef3 ) ...
But when i add the dsList1 i have a error that say :

```
"The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class EnergySolution\\ApiBundle\\Entity\\DataSource, but is an instance of class Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection. You can avoid this error by setting the \"data_class\" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection to an instance of EnergySolution\\ApiBundle\\Entity\\DataSource.""
```

Why my multiple option seem not working ?

Edit add mapping:

```
    $table = $builder->getClassMetadata()->getTableName();
    $builder
        ->setTable('chart_energy_goal')
        ->createField('name', Type::STRING)
            ->nullable()
        ->build()
        ->createField('title1', Type::STRING)
            ->nullable()
        ->build()
        ->createManyToOne('dsRef1', DataSource::class)
            ->cascadeAll()
        ->build()
        ->createManyToMany('dsList1', DataSource::class)
            ->setJoinTable("{$table}_dsList1")
            ->addJoinColumn("{$table}_id", 'id')
        ->build()
        ->createField('goal1', Type::FLOAT)
        ->build()
        ->createField('title2', Type::STRING)
            ->nullable()
        ->build()
        ->createManyToOne('dsRef2', DataSource::class)
            ->cascadeAll()
        ->build()
        ->createManyToMany('dsList2', DataSource::class)
            ->setJoinTable("{$table}_dsList2")
            ->addJoinColumn("{$table}_id", 'id')
        ->build()
        ->createField('goal2', Type::FLOAT)
        ->build()
        ->createField('title3', Type::STRING)
            ->nullable()
        ->build()
        ->createManyToOne('dsRef3', DataSource::class)
            ->cascadeAll()
        ->build()
        ->createManyToMany('dsList3', DataSource::class)
            ->setJoinTable("{$table}_dsList3")
            ->addJoinColumn("{$table}_id", 'id')
        ->build()
        ->createField('goal3', Type::FLOAT)
        ->build()
    ;
```

DataSource::class

```
    $builder = new ClassMetadataBuilder($metadata);
    $builder
        ->setTable('data_sources')
        ->setCustomRepositoryClass(EntityRepository::class)
        ->createField('id', Type::INTEGER)
        ->columnName('id')
        ->makePrimaryKey()
        ->generatedValue()
        ->build()
        ->addManyToOne('computedValue', ComputedValue::class)
        ->addManyToOne('probeData', ProbeData::class)
        ->addManyToOne('probeData', ManualData::class)
    ;
```

Edit crap solution :

After multiple try i found my formBuilder return something like

```
['computedValue' => [], 'probeData' => [], 'probeData' => []]
```

instead of

```
[dataSource ...]
```

So i Transforme the data like this.

```
    $builder->get('dsList1')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($dsListAsArray) {
                // never edit the form
                return $dsListAsArray;
            },
            function ($ArrayOfDataSources) {
                // transform list of 'dataSource' to liste of dataSource obj.
                $collection = new ArrayCollection();
                $propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessorBuilder()
                    ->enableExceptionOnInvalidIndex()
                    ->getPropertyAccessor()
                ;
                foreach ($ArrayOfDataSources as $dataSourceType => $dataSourcesArray) {
                    foreach ($dataSourcesArray as $dataSourceArray) {
                        $dataSource = new DataSource();
                        $propertyAccessor->setValue($dataSource, $dataSourceType, $dataSourceArray);
                        $collection->add($dataSource);
                    }
                }
                return $collection;
            }
        ))
    ;
```

Comment: where does `$multiple` come from? also, i assume your form builder needs a `property_path` for the arraycollections (to select the first entry). see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path

Comment: Field options from parent form.
I find the origin of the error, the form handle didn't make the 'dataSource' objet.
I get a array with 'computedValue'/ 'probeData' and 'manualData' with key, and for each key i get a array with value ...

Comment: added some more hints to my comment, sry.

Comment: I didn't want using this form for edit the entity, so i make some 'crap' with a modelTransfomer.

Comment: please add that to your question as an update, in the comments it's absolutely unreadable

Answer (score 1):

okay, as far as i can tell `DataSourceType` can handle only one `DataSource` (not an array of them).

As I assume from your data transformer, that `dsList1` is a many-to-many field, thus an array or `ArrayCollection` (or similar), probably coming from doctrine. It's probably an `ArrayCollection` of `DataSource`s?

Now, the error message given implies exactly that that's the problem, you provide an `ArrayCollection` where a `DataSource` is expected.

In my opinion you have two options:

#### option 1. really just render the first data source

If your dsList1 is really only *one* entity all the time (although the question is, why it's a many-to-many, but let's say legacy reasons), you could access the *first* datasource in the collection by adapting your data transformer accordingly:

```
$builder->get('dsList1')
    ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($dsListAsArray) {
            // ### here you get a list, but want only the first entry? ###
            return reset($dsListAsArray); // returns first element
        },
        function ($ArrayOfDataSources) {
            $collection = new ArrayCollection();
            // stuff you already wrote, BUT, see text below
            return $collection;
        }
    ))
;
```

however, your second function in the callback transformer gets ONE `DataSource` and thus must turn a single `DataSource` into an `ArrayCollection` of `DataSources`, which is

```
$builder->get('dsList1')
    ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($dsListAsArray) {
            // ### here you get a list, but want only the first entry? ###
            return reset($dsListAsArray); // returns first element
        },
        function ($dataSource) {
            return new ArrayCollection([$dataSource]); 
        }
    ))
;
```

#### option 2. just render it as a collection

turn your ("parent") forms `dsList1` field into a collection, since it only is supposed to have one entry:

```
    // in the file header part add (if not already there):  
    // use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

    ->add('dsList1', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => DataSourceType::class, 
        'entry_options' => [
            'site' => $site,
            'multiple' => true, // <-- can probably scrap this one?!
            'label_format' => 'form.%name%List1',
        ],
    ])
```

and you should be golden. On the logical form stuff. However, the templates will render this weirdly, probably... but you can update your form rendering, probably, by overriding the form_widget code with some custom block_prefix or something. (I guess you can figure this out from the symfony docs)

also, check out the CollectionType options, where you can (and possibly should) deny adding/removing (I believe the default is, that you can't anyway) and make a constraint, that there's always one (or none?).

as a comment: I would advise to not return an `ArrayCollection` from the entity on `get{CollectionField}()`, and in the `set{CollectionField}` expect an array and create the `ArrayCollection` on the spot there (or better: modify the existing one, so unnecessary updates are avoided ...)

and obligatory notice: since symfony 2.8 is not maintained anymore ... you should probably think about upgrading ... but I suppose this is not going to happen. ;o)

#### option 3. multiplexing like crazy - don't do it!

now, as far as I can tell, you wanted to turn your `DataSourceType` into being able to handle multiple `DataSource`s, by providing the `multiple` option. To do this, you would have to do some evil logic to somehow manage this, multiplexing an `ArrayCollection` of `DataSource`s into what the form expects to be a single `DataSource` (logic TBD) as a data transformer and do the same in reverse (logic TBD as well, and it's shaky af).

I would advise against it, you remove almost all advantages using the data_class of a `DataSource` by breaking into some incestuous Pseudo-`DataSource` or maybe even an array that resembles a `DataSource`. just to be able to use the same form. it's not worth it really. Keep the object. If you're certain there's always just one data source in your dsList[123], then just use one of the other options. if there might be another data source, option 2 is probably the preferred one. I would prefer it, TBH.